# Maven modules use different versions of same library and parent compile gives error

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, multi-module

I have a springboot project which uses package javax.servlet from org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-ember-core9.0.34. (this is coming from springboot)

I have another maven project (API project) which uses this javax.servlet but with version 2.3

Now I have created a parent maven project which includes above 2 projects as modules.
When I individually compile the springboot project, everything is fine.
But when I compile the parent project, it takes the javax.servlet.api version 2.3 to compile the springboot project and gives error, since a method is not available in 2.3 which is being used by springboot.

How to solve this?

**Please find a sample source code here:** https://github.com/abmjunaed/maven-multi-project-error

*I have added very minimal code to reproduce the scenario so that you can have a look and help!*

In the External Libraries of IntelliJ, I can see both libs and maven from the parent project is taking the javax-servlet-api:2.3 to compile the springBoot project and giving the error

[image]

Comment: So where did you define the version(s) of `javax.servlet.api`?

Comment: In the API project.

Comment: Then this will not influence the build of the other project. The error is somewhere else.

Comment: I have found the solution and posted it, and can't beleive it! Do you have any explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution and I can't believe it!

Dependency to **spring-boot-starter-web** was after the dependency of the **library project** and that was causing the problem.

Now I have added

> spring-boot-starter-web

as the first dependency and

> lib-project

as the 2nd dependency and everything works fine!

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency> <!--1st dependency-->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>library</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: It would be sensible to have a look at `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out where the problematic dependency comes in.

Comment: I highly appreciate your feedback, I tried mvn dependency:tree but couldn't understand.
Please find a sample source code here: https://github.com/abmjunaed/maven-multi-project-error
I have added very minimal code to reproduce the scenario so that you can have a look and help! Thanks!

Comment: Should "lib" and "library" be the same?

Comment: Sorry for the typo in my answer, I updated now. Github code is the single point of truth :)

Answer (score 0):

You should put the correct version of the javax.servlet dependency in the parent module's pom.This will override the javax.servlet dependency mentioned in the api project. To find the correct version you will have to hit and try with javax.servlet versions , the latest spring boot package for this should support version 2.3. Give it a try!!

Comment: I have found the solution and posted it, and can't beleive it! Do you have any explanation?

Comment: I highly appreciate your feedback, Please find a sample source code here: github.com/abmjunaed/maven-multi-project-error 
I have added very minimal code to reproduce the scenario so that you can have a look and help! Thanks!